# How can I be of service?

Tags: discussion

No really, how..

Since I signed up for this site, I've been receiving the best help and advice while studying maths, and I aprreciate it, a LOT. I include all of my working out and have learned how to set out a proper question *(Not including meta)*. The problem is, I feel as though I'm leeching off the communities intellect and giving nothing back. The reason I can't really answer m(any) questions is due to the fast that I don't know how.. I'm only in year 11 and to help those in need (most of the questions I look at possess OP's ranging from universities to out-of-the-world). What I'm wondering is, is there anyway I can give back, with my feasable knowledge? Which compares like nothing when juxtaposed with most of the people here.

Comment: If there aren't people around to contribute good questions, then the site is rather pointless. The best way to give back is to continue asking good questions, upvoting and accepting the answers; when you have more experience, then help out by answering questions too.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, but I also have the urge to help and when I can actually help someone it will feel amazing, to know that I am capable to share some of my wisdom to aid them with whatever project they are working on, unfortunately at this moment in time, it isn't that easy, but I'm still gonna find a way to help, some how.. Thank you! And don't worry, my questions will only ever always continue to increase in quality.

Comment: Similar question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3529/asking-a-lot-of-question-but-not-answering-other-people-questions (Perhaps you can find something useful also when you look at the related questions on the right.)

Comment: Asking good questions is not leeching. Occasionally there will be questions well within your capacity. If you give a good answer, it's a good answer -- it doesn't matter what your age is or your qualifications -- and if you sometimes give an imperfect answer, that's a chance to learn, too. My goodness, when I started using SE, some of my early answers were pretty ordinary (and many, deservedly, got no upvotes at all). You also help by *voting*, suggesting edits to questions, flagging posts. When you pass 500 reputation you can start helping on some of the review queues.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(I am expanding my comment slightly.)

Since math.SE is meant to be a question and answer site, there need to be people around to contribute good questions; otherwise, the whole idea is rather pointless.

> The problem is, I feel as though I'm leeching off the communities intellect and giving nothing back.

But you are giving back: By asking well-thought-out questions, you're helping to make the site better; you can also contribute by voting up and accepting answers to your questions. Another good way to help out is to compile the knowledge you've gained from the answers you received, making it more concise for future users (e.g. by answering your own question with a summary of the help you received, and hints worked out fully).

Once you have sufficient experience, you can also contribute by writing answers, and thus help to educate the next group of question-askers. Everyone has to start off inexperienced.

Comment: I will! I've already tried to find topics I may be of help to, (Still looking...), but I make sure my questions are the best they can be, and hopefully soon my knowledge will be sufficient for the next group of quesion-askers, as you said. Thank you for this reply!

Comment: I would also add that writing really outstanding questions is just as difficult as answering them.  There is an art to asking a good question.  Don't feel bad if you can't answer things yet - instead, focus on making your questions more cogent, universal, and engaging.